# How to write yaml-collections with "Ruby array look" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I'm creating some yaml files from ruby hashes and arrays, using `YAML.dump` to create the ruby_hash_with_arrays, like

```
file = File.open(original_dir.join(probe), 'w')  
file.write(YAML.dump(ruby_hash_with_arrays))
file.close
```

It's all good. Ruby arrays like: `{"Count" => [101,102,103,104]}`
Turn into:

```
  Count:
  - 101
  - 102
  - 103
  - 104
```

But I have big arrays, so to make them more readable, I would like to have them stay in the format of:

```
Count:[101,102,103,104]
```

What is a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Write it manually? The YAML serializer just does it however is valid, not however is subjectively pretty.

Answer (score 0):

> Count: [101,102,103,104]

should work fine.

then, you can access the values as YAML["Count"][0].